# Creating Local SQL Database in UWP application

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017, windows-10-desktop

How can I create a local database for a Windows 10 desktop App (Software for Windows 10 Computer) in visual studio 2017?

I want to create a Windows 10 application and to have a local database to the Computer itself. I don't want any online database like Azure.

I am working on a software for tuition classes.Where the User Enters the data of Students (more than 2000 student's data and some Documents(Images), approx 5 to 10 new entries every day So I want everything offline).I also want a feature of taking a backup of DB and Store it on Cloud when the user is connected to the Internet.
Please Show me the correct path.

I also find some solutions like SQLite but is it work for Windows 10 PC Software? Are there any other solutions like MySQL?

A have created a database and table using SQL server object explorer in visual studio-2017, but I don't know how to connect it with my xaml and c# files.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to create a Windows 10 application and to have a local database to the Computer itself. I don't want any online database like Azure.

If you want to create a local database for your UWP application. you could refer to [SQLite databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases) official documentation. And here is code [sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sqlite-Sample-for-Windows-ad3af7ae).

> A have created a database and table using SQL server object explorer in visual studio-2017, but I don't know how to connect it with my xaml and c# files.

If you want to connect a SQL server database, you could refer to **[How to access data from SQL Server database in Windows Store app](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-access-data-from-5f2602ec#content)**. And it has video tutorial.